# Http post get response Android

Tags: java, android, http, post

I want to retrieve some data from an external web page. When I'm navigating on it and I click to show this data, I see from the developer console (under "network") that a http post call is been making. If I open it, I can see the data I want retrieve from my android app and I want to get that string response.

But I don't know how to "build" the http post request. This is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/portusgwt/rpc");

    httppost.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Length", "172");
    httppost.addHeader("X-GWT-Module-Base", "http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/portusgwt/");
    httppost.addHeader("X-GWT-Permutation", "3DEDE3A69CBBE62D4C3F58BF7278538F");
    httppost.addHeader("Origin", "http://portus.puertos.es");
    httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    httppost.addHeader("Referer", "http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/?locale=es");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,ca;q=0.4");
    httppost.addHeader("AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH", "AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3");
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8");
    httppost.addHeader("Host", "portus.puertos.es");

    //I think I need to add the payload here
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", ""));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d("TAG", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I really don't know about http protocols, so I don't know what data of the http post request (that I can see from the developer console) I need to add. This is the http post request I see:
[image]

I'm not sure If I need to add all the headers and how to add the payload.
Even I do not know if I can do this, so I will be very grateful I anyone can guide me some

Thanks!!

Comment: Gonzalo where is our coversation about this some days ago? It looks if you are going to repeat to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like that, and convert the String returned in JSONObject or whatever. Adapt it to your code if you need it, but I think it's "almost" a generic solution.

```
private String callServer(List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs,String path) {

        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        String result = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(path);


        //Your headers here
        //I'm afraid there are too much headers. Try cleaning and choosing only the neccessary ones.

        httppost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", "172");
        httppost.setHeader("X-GWT-Module-Base", "http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/portusgwt/");
        httppost.setHeader("X-GWT-Permutation", "3DEDE3A69CBBE62D4C3F58BF7278538F");
        httppost.setHeader("Origin", "http://portus.puertos.es");
        httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        httppost.setHeader("Referer", "http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/?locale=es");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,ca;q=0.4");
        httppost.setHeader("AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH", "AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Host", "portus.puertos.es");    

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Even tough, I recommend you to use this component for rest APIs and HTTP Connections:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

Take a look and evaluate if it worths to you. It allows you to manage "no connection", show/hide dialogs before and after the call (or whatever) and some more features.

I hope I would help you. ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the code! But the problen is that I don't know how to add the headers and the payload of the request. I think I understand the code, the problem is I don't know how to add the data of the request. Could you take a look to my image and tell me what to add please? Thanks!!

Comment: Oh. I'm afraid that your question is not focusing your problem.Anyway, using the component I've recommended you you only have to give a Set<Pair<String,String> with headerName and value.. that's all.

If you want to do it manually, change addHeader for setHeader. For instance:

request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8");

I hardly ever use headers different from "Content-Type", "application/json", but it's up to you!

Comment: Thanks for answering! Perfect, I didn't know that I don't need to add all the headers. How should I add the payload? I think it's the data that the server will read and will return a response based on it. Is it right? How should I add it because I believe it is not a pair of values...

Comment: Once, I recommend you to use the component. With it, you only have to define a JSON and it's send in background. If you want to follow this way, you set your httpost body with the parameters you need.

StringEntity formEntity = new StringEntity("yourPayload");
   putRequest.setEntity(formEntity);

I also recommend you build your payload as JSON.  

Mark the answer as the correct one if it really is... please!